# How to enable usb cp21x mode in android?

Tags: android, linux, usb, kernel

As I need, in my application I want to access a device which is connect to my galaxy tab via mini-usb. My device is designed to communicate with CP21x usb standart. This mode is not enabled in default compile. How can I enable this feature in android kernel.

Thanks.

Comment: If you literally want to use the kernel driver method, the first step is to successfully rebuild your existing kernel from source **without any changes**, install it, and then test it.  Then you can enable the module in the kernel config if already present in your sources, or copy in the source from an upstream kernel of similar vintage.  **But this is the old method:** for the past several android releases, the preferred method is not to use a kernel driver, but rather to talk raw USB operations to the peripheral from code in your app written against the Android USB Host APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use **FT312** .It designed for android applications.